# How do I change a value in an object but still keep certain values?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create to practice and create a function where in that if the count matches that price or is half the initial price to open and will also not reset to false, if the count drops back to 0.

Here is some example data:

```
openData = {
    count: 0,
    chest: [
      { id: 'Chest1', price: 50, open: false },
      { id: 'Chest2', price: 200, open: false },
      { id: 'Chest3', price: 500, open: false }
    ]
  };

("changes `open` to `true` when the count is equal to or larger than half the initial price of the id", function() {
  openData.count = 100;
  code.unlockedChest(openData.chest, openData.count);
  expect(openData.chest[0].open).to.equal(true);
  expect(openData.chest[1].open).to.equal(true);
  expect(openData.chest[2].open).to.equal(false);
});

('does not set `open` to `false` once a chest has been opened, even if the count drops again', function() {
  openData.count = 100;
  code.unlockedChest(openData.chest, openData.count);
  openData.count = 0;
  code.unlockedChest(openData.chest, openData.count);
  expect(openData.chest[0].open).to.equal(true);
  expect(openData.chest[1].open).to.equal(true);
  expect(openData.chest[2].open).to.equal(false);
});
```

});

Here is the idea that I have so far:

```
function unlockedChest (id, count) {
    if (count === chest.price || count <= chest.price) {
      return chest.open === true;
    } 
    if (chest.open === true) {
      return true; // trying to keep the value that it was changed to
    }

}
```

I have been trying to play around with this for a few hours and I don't think my logic is correct here as well, because what is throwing me off is the wording of 'half'.The output that I'm getting is expecting false to be true for the first spec.

I'm also wondering if this would be a case of using a loop possibly?

Any additional guidance would be appreciated on both specs!

Comment: `chest` is an **array of objects** that you're passing into your `unlockedChest` function. If you want to test each price in that function then you need to iterate over the array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update the value of `chest.open` based on the value of `chest.price`, but only if the chest is not already open (`chest.open` is not true).

You can accomplish this by checking for the open condition before you perform any other logic. If `chest.open == true` then there is no need to check the price, at least not as part of a function that updates `chest.open`.